# How to pass value from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How can I pass the value of lead_id to my attendance table?
Here is the code from my controller

```
$scores = Score::with('lead','subject')->get()->groupBy('lead_id');
```

I want to pass $scores here:

```
$atnds = DB::table('attendances')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total, status'))
    ->where('status', '=', 'P')
    ->whereBetween('days', [$from,$to])
    ->groupBy('status')
    **->where('lead_id','=',$scores)**
    ->get();
```

Both table Score and Attendance has lead_id is it possible to connect them? i want to perform total base on the lead_id from score table is equal to attendance table. with my code i'm getting this empty array[image]

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: noting i'm just getting empty array

Comment: try to var_dump your $scores to see what type of variable is it and if it has any value at all.

Answer (score 1):

`where` condition in eloquent expects a string/integer value to be pased and not a collection as you are trying to pass it.

After you get the results from this query:

they should be grouped by keys like:

```
$scores = Score::with('lead','subject')->get()->groupBy('lead_id');

Collection{
1 => Collection{somedata},
2 => Collection{somedata},
}
```

So i pressume you need only the keys from this collection:

```
  $atnds = DB::table('attendances')
 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total, status'))
 ->where('status', '=', 'P')
 ->whereBetween('days', [$from,$to])
 ->groupBy('status')
 ->whereIn('lead_id',$scores->pluck('lead_id')->toArray())
 ->get();
```

this is the result of DD$scores

```
 "id" => 62
        "subject_id" => 4
        "lead_id" => 5
        "uuid" => "36c850d0-9ec9-11e8-85e1-cdb65cbc1965"
        "created_at" => "2018-08-13 07:19:27"
        "updated_at" => "2018-08-13 07:19:27"
      ]
```

the **total** is not there

Comment: with this code im getting single return meaning only one of the lead id,

Comment: add the response maybe you hace only one lead to group by

Comment: sorry what is response?

Comment: the results sorry!

Comment: this is the result im getting at [{"total":64,"status":"P"}] only refers to one of the id

Comment: dd($scores); and add them to the question

Comment: i tried to dd($scores); but result does not include the result from $atnds

Comment: @Grace ok I see now do in whereIn : $scores->pluck('lead_id')->toArray();

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$scores = Score::with('lead','subject')->get();

$atnds = DB::table('attendances')
                 ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as total, status'))
                 ->where('status', '=', 'P')
                 ->whereBetween('days', [$from,$to])
                 ->groupBy('status')
                 ->whereIn('lead_id', array_column($scores->toArray(), 'lead_id'))
                 ->get();
```